# Link XML and XSLT files in an HTML file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am still learning how to use XML and XSL to create an HTML output file and have improved a lot thanks to stackoverflow.

I have an XML file that is auto generated but I cannot tell the XML file where the XSLT file is every time a new XML is created.
Is there a way to create an HTML file that when a user opens it, the HTML will "href" to the XML and XSLT and output it as the intended HTML result, in the same way a CSS or Javascript is included in an HTML.

Thank you,
Robin

This is the XML file when it is generated from a program we use...

```
<Root>
<Ticket>
<TicketStart Date="2012-10-22" />
<Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="0" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000026" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
<ClubcardPoints Opcode="96" Function="28" SchemeNo="40" PromNo="0" CardNo="1042540000026" QualSpend="30005" PointSpend="0" Points="6" BonusPoints="0" PromCount="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
<Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="1" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000026" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="30005" Date="2012-10-22" />
<TicketEnd Date="2012-10-22" />
</Ticket>
<Ticket>
<TicketStart Date="2012-10-22" />
<TicketEnd Date="2012-10-22" />
</Ticket>
<Events>
</Events>
<Ticket>
<TicketStart Date="2012-10-22" />
<Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="0" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000057" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
<ClubcardPoints Opcode="96" Function="28" SchemeNo="40" PromNo="0" CardNo="1042540000057" QualSpend="18025" PointSpend="0" Points="3" BonusPoints="0" PromCount="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
<Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="1" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000057" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="18025" Date="2012-10-22" />
<TicketEnd Date="2012-10-22" />
</Ticket>
<Events>
</Events>
</Root>
```

`

and currently I have to put this at the start of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLnice.xsl"?>
```

The XSL file looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
    <title>StoreLine Loyalty Sales</title>
      </head>
    <body>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
       <b>Loyal Customers</b>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    <table width="100%" border="3">
      <THEAD>
      <TR bgcolor="RGB(0, 204, 51)">
      <TD width="25%">
        <font color="white"><B>Account Number</B></font>
      </TD>
      <TD width="25%">
        <font color="white"><B>Points</B></font>
      </TD>
      <TD width="25%">
        <font color="white"><B>Date</B></font>
      </TD>
      <TD width="25%">
        <font color="white"><B>Qualified Spent</B></font>
      </TD>
      </TR>
      </THEAD>
    <TBODY>
    <xsl:for-each select="Root/Ticket/ClubcardPoints">
      <TR>
      <TD width="25%"><xsl:value-of select="@CardNo" /></TD>
      <TD width="25%"><xsl:value-of select="@Points" /></TD>
      <TD width="25%"><xsl:value-of select="@Date" /></TD>
      <TD width="25%"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@QualSpend div 100,'&#x52;#.##')" /></TD>
    </TR>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </TBODY>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`

With these files in the same folder, I double click the XML file and it presents me with a friendly report of the values I need in the XML. So rather if I could just double-click one HTML file and everytime a new XML is placed in the same folder, the HTML will find the XML and use the XSL as the style-sheet to present itself. Instead of having to manually update the XML everytime and tell it to use the XSL.

Also I have tried but unsuccessfully group the 'CardNo' and report how many times it was used, how much in total 'Points' were earned and how much was the 'qualified amount'. Instead of this long list of entries, like a consolidated report.

Thank you so much...

Here is the preferred output file...

```
<THEAD>
                <TR bgcolor="RGB(0, 204, 51)">
                    <TD width="25%"><font color="white"><B>Account Number</B></font></TD>
                    <TD width="25%"><font color="white"><B>Total Points</B></font></TD>
                    <TD width="25%"><font color="white"><B>Date</B></font></TD>
                    <TD width="25%"><font color="white"><B>Total Qualified Spent</B></font></TD>
                </TR>
            </THEAD>
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD width="25%">1042540000002</TD>
                    <TD width="25%">100</TD>
                    <TD width="25%">2012-10-22</TD>
                    <TD width="25%">R750.32</TD>
                </TR>
```

Comment: Can you provide the XML code you use to link to the XSLT manually. We may help more then.

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail; I don't quite understand. If you have both the XML and the XSLT, why can't you just transform it to HTML? Why would the HTML still need to refer to the XSLT once you view it?

Comment: Dear @Dabbler, I have updated this query as requested above. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're using XSLT to create HTML from your XML file. The regular way of doing this is to run an XSLT processor, giving it the XSLT and XML files. There is no need to modify the XML file in order to do this. You feed the XSLT and XML files to the processor, and it gives you the transformed output file, which will be HTML in your case.

I believe both Saxon and Altova have free versions of theit XSLT engines (alongside the commercial ones), so try downloading one of them and give it a try. You just need to call the XSLT engine from the command line. You can probably use Microsoft's engine, too, as long as you don't need XSLT 2.

Comment: Thank you @Dabbler for the advise, I will download it and give it a go. I will report back on progress.

Comment: Hi @Dabbler, I managed with Altova via CLI and works perfectly in an MS environment. Pitty its not platform independant, had a look at xinclude and jquery but does what asked. Thank you